# Doing a regular task after a specified time of day in Python everyday

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, parsing, time

I need to run some code to store my list of values that i collect during day affter 23:30 everday. For that purpose I used that code:

```
 def sayac_yaz():

    threading.Timer(3600, sayac_yaz).start()

    save_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    if (save_time.hour<23):
        return 

    print "Sayaclari kaydediyor"

    if mem.sayac_okuma_flag==0:
        save_dict=mem.readings_from_counters

    # Connecting to the database file
    conn2 = sqlite3.connect('tenantdata.sqlite')
    c2 = conn2.cursor()

    for idx in save_dict:
        sayac_value=save_dict[idx]
        actual_counter_id=idx
        if isinstance(sayac_value, float):
            # insert a new row with the current date and time, e.g., 2014-03-06
            c2.execute('''INSERT INTO tenant_counter VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)''' , (actual_counter_id, save_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), save_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'), save_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), sayac_value))
        else:
            # insert a new row with the current date and time, e.g., 2014-03-06
            c2.execute('''INSERT INTO tenant_counter VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)''' , (actual_counter_id, save_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), save_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'), save_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 'Error!'))
    conn2.commit()
    conn2.close()
    return
```

As i understand, here i can only run that code every hour after thread started. How can I change ıt so that it will work after 23:30 once everyday? For me especially this time part is ımportant.

Comment: What about using OS scheduler? cron for Unix, standard scheduler for Windows? It is better, than writing your own scheduler.

Comment: but its a code snıppet in my application. And my application is not run based on schedule. Only that snıppet.

Comment: But you'll have to *keep* your application running for this to work. Using the OS scheduler as m9_psy wrote is a much better solution than re-inventing the wheel...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to use the system scheduler (crontab on Linux), because it is designed for this purpose.

If crontab is out of your reach, you have to keep your script running, and check current time periodically:

```
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    # call the function between 23:30 and 23:35
    if now.hour == 23 and 30 <= now.minute <35:
       sayac_yaz()
    time.sleep(5*60)
```